# Ryanair flight time change

Tags: air-travel, europe, ryanair

I have a flight booked with Ryanair, scheduled about three months from now. They have recently notified me about a slight schedule change (departure and arrival moving 5 minutes later). I got an email mentioning this together with a link that I should use to confirm that I am ok with the changes. I did not click that link yet.

Do I have any choice? As my plans have changed, if this is allowed, I would happily choose to not accept the changes and cancel my booking to get the money back. I was in similar situation already once with Wizzair (although the schedule change was a lot bigger then, about 2-3 hours) and I could cancel my booking. I looked through Ryanair's website and didn't find such possibility, on the other hand I know they are good at hiding things advantegous to passengers in obscure corners nobody can find.

Comment: You have other plans due to a five minute delay - seriously???!

Comment: Did I say this anywhere? I have other plans for other reasons

Comment: you asked what were your options given this email about a five minute delay.  You would have not asked this question had there not been a five minute delay as you would have never got an email.  You stated your plans have changed...so this to me means even if there wasn't a five minute delay you had other plans - so why did you not call ryanair about this and asked to cancel the flight and only asked after they sent you a five minute delay email?

Answer (score 7):

This is what Ryanair says on their website. So for a 5 min change you are not going to be able to cancel.

> Occasionally due to unforeseen circumstances flight times may have to be changed.
>   If this happens we do our best to contact all customers via the email and mobile phone number you provided at the time of booking.
>
> We also recommend to review your flight booking prior to departure via My Bookings.
>
> If a flight time is changed by more than 2 hours before or after the original departure time, and no suitable alternative flight is available, you can apply for a full refund for the unused flight.
>
> Please note that we are not liable for any prepaid expenses directly or indirectly related to the booking affected by the flight time change.